# Ссылка $$ на $_SERVER

Tags: php

```
$key = '_GET';
var_dump($$key) // array(0) {}

$key = '_SERVER';
var_dump($$key) // Notice: Undefined variable: _SERVER
```

OpenServer 5.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, внимательно прочти [Документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php). В окошке в конце статьи написано:

> **Внимание** Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что переменные переменных не
>   могут использоваться с Суперглобальными массивами PHP. Переменная
>   *$this* также является особой, на нее нельзя ссылаться динамически.

То есть такой синтаксис использовать с суперглобальными массивами нельзя!